# What is my error in the dated if macro? The value returned is in a a time format

Tags: excel, vba, date, datediff

Below is the Sub to count the years between 2 dates.  No value is displayed in the cell(i,3) and when i update to a MsgBox a time value is displayed.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Sub EE_DatedIF()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim yrDiff As Long
    Dim d1 As Date
    Dim d2 As Date

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

    LastRow1 = wb1.Sheets("Carrier").range("E:E").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 10 To LastRow1
        d1 = wb1.Sheets("Settings").Cells(i, 1)
        d2 = wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Cells(i, 24)
        yrDiff = DateDiff("yy", d1, d2)
        wb1.Sheets("Settings").Cells(i, 3) = yrDiff
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get a correct result with `yrDiff = DateDiff("yyyy", d1, d2)` ? Are you running under `On Error Resume Next` ? `yrDiff` is a Long and can only reproduce time badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other problems, your attempt to retrieve the last populated row in column E should not be deemed reliable. Better with something closer to this.

```
With wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Range("E:E")
    lastRow1 = .Find("*", after:=.Cells(1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

Comment: I updated the cell reference (i, 1) to (1,1) and removed the *.  It s is working as expected now.  Thanks again.